# Error : Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')

Tags: javascript, php

Hi i'm trying to build uploadfile form with javascript i used other web page and its worked when i copied code to main index file it had error and i cant fix it
i used i youtube video to learn uploadfile form and i did it right but when i want to copy form section to my main file getting error in secound querySelector

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home Page </title>
        <link href="css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link type="image/png" sizes="96x96" rel="icon" href="/images/icon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>

                
    </head>
    <body class="loggedin">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="./logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Log Out</a>

            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasTop" aria-controls="offcanvasTop">Message Board</button>
              <button class="btn btn-dark navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="./home.php">Home</a>
                      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="./profile.php">Profile</a>
                                        </li>
                                  
                      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          Records
                        </a>
                      </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <br><br>
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-top" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasTop" aria-labelledby="offcanvasTopLabel">
            
                <div class="offcanvas-body"></div>
            </div>        
        <div class="content">
        
                <div class="container">
        <div class="row border">
            <div class="col border">
                
            </div>
            
            <div class="col border">
                <form action="#">
                    <input type="file" class="file-input" name="file-input">
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt" style="margin-top:20px;font-size: 30px;"></i>
                </form>
            <br>
            <section class="progress-area"></section>
            <section class="uploaded-area">
            <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-group-divider">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
            </section>
            </div><br>
        
            </div>
    </div>    
            
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

js file were error is happening(secound line):

```
const form=document.querySelector("form"),
fileInput=form.querySelector(".file-input"),
progressArea=document.querySelector(".progress-area"),
uploadedArea=document.querySelector(".uploaded-area");
```

Comment: Try putting `defer` on you script loading, your trying to access the `form` before the DOM is loaded.. `<script src="script.js" defer></script>`   And then this -> `fileInput=form.querySelector(` will fail.